# Saving an entity that contains nested entities in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Imagine having three entities A, B, C as follows:

```java
class A {
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    B b;
}
```

```java
class B {
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    C c;
}
```

```java
class C {
    Long id;
}
```

When saving an object `A` that has an object `B` inside and that object `B` contains only the id (already exists in the database), the returned object from the save method of `A` repository does not contain the full `B` object (i.e. does not contain `C`).

Is there a way to get the B object without using the `B` repository?

Answer (score 0):

The Object from the .save()-operation returned by the jpa-implementation (should be hibernate) can be used to get the b-instance by simply calling a.getB() and with that b-instance c can be accessed by calling b.getC().

If you turn on logging for spring jpa as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) you can see the extra activities started by the jpa-implementation when accessing b or c (called lazy loading). This can be changed by switching to eager loading (e.g. by using a fetch-/loadgraph, as described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs)). Because these are two or more activities on the database, a transactional context should be used (@transactional, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring)). As commented by Mahmoud the default behavior is eager-loading.

Comment: Isn't eager loading the default behavior for `@ManyToOne` relations?